# What is meant by JSON end point in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

What is meant by "create JSON API end point"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any more context, I'm going to suggest that it refers to routes and controller actions that return JSON as their output. These can be used in AJAX calls from a heavier client application. They allow the application to handle all the 'view magic' in browser rather than with full page refreshes relying on .erb/.haml templates.